# Python plot clusters: high data dimension

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, cluster-analysis

I am using python `sklearn.cluster` to do clustering. I only have **225** data and each data is of dimension **250**. Now I want to plot the resultant clusters. I tried to use the method introduced in [Plot multi-dimension cluster to 2D plot python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26645642/plot-multi-dimension-cluster-to-2d-plot-python), but because in this answer `matplotlib.mlab.PCA` is used so I got the error

```
we assume data in a is organized with numrows>numcols
```

Now I don't know how to plot my clusters with so high dimensions and make it easy and intuitive to visualize. Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the page on [manifold learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html).

> "Manifold Learning can be thought of as an attempt to generalize linear frameworks like PCA to be sensitive to non-linear structure in data."

Here are some examples of the results of various algorithms with a low dimensional dataset.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helps me a lot!